# SD Card limits or faults

Tags: sd-card

I have 3 new 32gb SD cards (Class 10, xc I).
I put 20.3gb of data, including  images, videos, ISOs, a DVD, PDFs, debs, tar balls on them. But after writing them all, some files are missing, and some of what remains appear corrupt, even before safe removal, more problems arise after a safe removal.

While "space used" is correct, in properties for the cards, linux only finds, 9.5 to 15gb of data in the folders

Is this what I should expect, on the basis the that SDcards use compression and this data does not compress well(shrinks little or expands), or are these card malfunctioning?
Default format is FAT, I tried exFAT on one of them, didn't help.

Comment: FAT filesystem corrupts external media regularly. All your files are good, it's just corrupted.

Comment: Is the card from a reliable source? Sometimes dubious vendors label and format the cards with much larger file systems than they can hold, so some data just gets saved nowhere...

Comment: I have also reformatted two the cards of the cards, one of them using vista thorough formatting, one time in exfat it didn't make much of an improvement.

I used meld Diff, to compare the cards files to the original. This is how I know what damage there is.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my previous comment, that the cards did maintain approximately 32GB in capacity when reformatted, so dodgy factory formatting does not seem to be and issue.